# Display numbers up to two decimals places without trailing zeros

Tags: javascript, numbers, parsefloat

In my code I will be accepting multiple values, for example:

```
8.7456
8.7
8
```

and I need to have them appear as

```
8.74
8.7
8
```

i.e. display up to two decimal place.

I understand that `.toFixed(2)` will help me with the first value, but on the 2nd and 3rd value there will be trailing zeroes that I do not want.

How to produce my desired results?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`Number.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to round the number up to two digits and format as a string. Then use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to chop off trailing zeros:

```js
[8.7456, 8.745, 8.74, 8.7, 8].forEach(function(num) {
  var str = num.toFixed(2).replace(/\.?0+$/, "");
  console.log(num, str);
});
```

Comment: okay okay you got it, no more updates! i altered your second iteration to what you posted here (because of the `8.` result) thanks for your help!

Comment: rounding is okay, i initially didn't want to round but it turns out that I should. however, if you wanted to post an example of how to do this without rounding I am sure someone at some point will use it

Answer (score 5):

Multiply by 100, `floor`, divide by 100.

```
var n = 8.7456;
var result = Math.floor(n * 100) / 100; // 8.74
```

Edit: if you’re looking at this question after the fact, this is probably not what you want. It satisfies the odd requirement of having `8.7456` appear as `8.74`. See also [the  relevant comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215770/display-numbers-up-to-two-decimals-places-without-trailing-zeros/10215818#comment13122758_10216503).

Comment: well, maybe my computer is "special" but if n is 8.7 this calculation spits back 8.69. thoughts?

Comment: apparently, per JS, 8.7 * 100 is 869.99999999. How can it mess up something this simple?

Comment: floating point arithmetic is not precise and you bump into rounding off errors every now and then.